# ExpressionEngine: check if taxonomy is empty

Tags: taxonomy

I'm very new to EE but I can't seem to find how to check if the following is returning empty nodes:

```
{exp:taxonomy:nav tree_id="1" display_root="no" ul_css_class="clearfix"  root_node_entry_id="{entry_id}"}
    <a href="{node_url}">{node_title}</a>
{/exp:taxonomy:nav}
```

I'm doing this because I have a toggle button for the menu but I want to hide it if there are no children nodes for the current page.

Comment: Lily, is your desired solution on the front-end or back-end?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that addon at all, but have you tried a few simple conditionals? Ex:

```
{exp:taxonomy:nav tree_id="1" display_root="no" ul_css_class="clearfix"  root_node_entry_id="{entry_id}"}

    {if node_title != "" || node_id != ""}

        <a href="{node_url}">{node_title}</a>

    {if:else}

        <!-- empty node! -->

    {/if}

{/exp:taxonomy:nav}
```

Comment: ah, I apologize. I should have mentioned I needed to check if the node is empty outside of the taxonomy loop.

Comment: On the back-end or front-end? Back-end will require using https://github.com/croxton/Stash or turning on PHP template parsing; front-end will require some jQuery action. Please edit your question with the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

While in a channel:entries loop, I see if this entry is in a taxonomy tree by running this:

```
{if "{exp:taxonomy:get_node}{this_node_title}{/exp:taxonomy:get_node}" != ""}
```